# Not able to fetch the data using manyToOne using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, many-to-one

I am using Spring Data, JPA and not able to fetch the data using `manyToOne` relationship.

I have 2 entities  `Employee`, `EmployeeTransferRequest`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_detail")
public class EmployeeDetail{

private Employee employee;

private Long empId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", insertable = false, nullable = false,updatable = false)
    public Employee getEmployee() {
       return _student;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
      this.employee = employee;
    }


    @Column(name = "emp_id", updatable = false)
    public Long getEmpId() {
       return empId;
    }


    public void setEmpId(Long empId) {
       this.empId = empId;
    }

    }
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "employee")
    class Employee
    {
        @Override
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = " emp_id")
        public Long getEmpId() {
            return _id;
            // Other Fields of Employee class ..
        }
    }

public interface EmployeeTransferRequestRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeTransferRequest, UUID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<EmployeeTransferRequest>
    {
        default EmployeeTransferRequest findOneUUID  transferRequestId) {
           return findOne(employeeTransferRequest.id.eq(transferRequestId);
        }
    }
```

I did not map `EmployeeTransferRequest` from `Employee` entity side. Its only `uni-directional` from `EmployeeTransferRequest` only.

When I am calling `findOne`, I am able to get all the information from `EmployeeTransferRequest`, but not getting `Employee` Information, getting `null`.

Could you please help.

Comment: did you try changing FetchType from LAZY to EAGER?

Comment: @melli-182, yes  I have tried by changing LAZY to EAGER, but it did not work.

Comment: please post actual code. This code does not compile: capital Class, missing parens. You are annotating the getters, so hibernate should use the setters to fill in values, but since there are none, this can't work. But then ... this is not the code you are actually using ...

Comment: @ Jens Schauder , I have made the required changes to understand , could you please check now

Comment: Please post the EmployeeTransferRequest as well. If you don't put a space between @ and my name in a comment I'll get a notification that you are talking to me.

Comment: @Venky Where you able to resolve this ? Pls share your solution. I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

It is because you've specified the mapping as `insertable=false`.  This means when you create the transfer request, the relationship won't be persisted, resulting in `null` when you query the request in the future.

Comment: I am not using Employee Object to persist the employee info, for persistence I am using empId property, I have updated the code, please check and advise.

Answer (score 0):

use of following annotations worked for me :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "emp_id")
```

instead of using :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", insertable = false, nullable = false,updatable = false)
```